# Spread imageViews evenly over tablerow

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-tablelayout

Like the title says, I have problems in spreading ImageViews evenly over tableRows. My xml is:

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
  <ProgressBar/>
  <TextView/>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
       </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

After the Activity is started a dynamical Table is created with the following code:

```
     for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      tableRow = new TableRow(this);
      tableRow.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
              ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

      tableRow.setId(i + 1);
      tableRow.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.shelfboard);
      tableRow.setPadding(20, 0, 20, 0);
      tableRow.setOnClickListener(thisvariable);

      tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
  }
```

Now I want to add different numbers of ImageViews of the same width for each tableRow to each tableRow.

I have 4 TableRows

- add 2 ImageViews to tableRow 1
- add 5 ImageViews to tableRow 2
- add 3 ImageViews to tableRow 3
- add 7 ImageViews to tableRow 4

My Code is:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < adpList.size(); i++) {
            int row = adpList.get(i).getShelfBoard();
            if (row==1) {
                int productsPerBoard = 2;
                int width = (tableLayout.getWidth()) / productsPerBoard;

                TableRow.LayoutParams tlp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(width, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

                productPicture = new ImageView(this);
                r = (TableRow) findViewById(row);
                productPicture.setLayoutParams(tlp);
            }
            if (row==2) {
                int productsPerBoard = 5;
                int width = (tableLayout.getWidth()) / productsPerBoard;


                TableRow.LayoutParams tlp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(width, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                productPicture = new ImageView(this);
                productPicture.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
                r = (TableRow) findViewById(row);

                productPicture.setLayoutParams(tlp);
            }
            if (row==3) {
                int productsPerBoard = 3;
                int width = (tableLayout.getWidth()) / productsPerBoard;
               TableRow.LayoutParams tlp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(width, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

                productPicture = new ImageView(this);
                r = (TableRow) findViewById(row);
                productPicture.setLayoutParams(tlp);
            }
            if (row==4) {
                int productsPerBoard = 7;
                int width = tableLayout.getWidth() / productsPerBoard;

                TableRow.LayoutParams tlp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(width, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

                productPicture = new ImageView(this);
                r = (TableRow) findViewById(row);
                productPicture.setLayoutParams(tlp);
            }
          productPicture.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
          r.addView(productPicture);
```

Unfortunately every row has only two pictures. It always takes the width of the first board. My Output:

[image]

How can I add different numbers of ImageViews to each row?

Answer (score 0):

I thought too complicated. Changing the LayoutParams solved my problem:

```
    r = (TableRow) findViewById(shelfboard);
    productPicture = new ImageView(this);

    TableRow.LayoutParams tlp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f);
    tlp.setMargins(0, 20, 0, 50);
    productPicture.setLayoutParams(tlp);
```